# Workflow when using Emacs, Arduino-makefile and Serial monitor?

Tags: serial

I'm trying to develop code, compile, upload and use the Serial monitor for debugging of a script for an Arduino Pro Mini. I'm using Emacs as my IDE. I'm having trouble determining the exact sequence of commands to do this most efficiently. What I'd like to do is:

- Edit my code, compile and upload from Emacs (able to do this now)
- Switch to a window running minicom (or putty, etc.) and observe the debug output.
- rinse and repeat

My problem is that now, I have to stop and start minicom each iteration, after I upload the code. Sometimes, restarting minicom causes my Arduino to reboot, and that then displays the debugging output correctly. Sometimes, it takes two minicom restarts to accomplish this. Also, if I don't kill minicom before uploading, it just prints garbage to the screen, and seems to hang. I'm hoping for something like the Arduino IDE Serial monitor, that just runs continuously, and that correctly displays the debugging output.

Ideally, I'd like help coming up with the exact commands to run a Serial monitor that wouldn't require stopping and starting it. Is this possible?

Thanks for all your suggestions and advice.

-Kevin

Comment: that is the advantage of the Serial Monitor in IDE. IDE disconnects it before upload and connects it back after upload.

Comment: There's no way to disconnect and reconnect minicom remotely. All you can do is kill the process, and then manually restart it.